# How maxdepth and mindepth works with find command?

Tags: unix, find

I want to know how the maxdepth and mindepth works with find command.
And also want to know how the below command works,

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 5 -name 'file1'
```

Comment: This looks like XY problem: http://xyproblem.info/ Can you clarify the end goal, the big idea?

Comment: Just want to know how this one works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [man page of find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

> ```
>    -maxdepth levels
>           Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of
>           directories below the starting-points.  -maxdepth 0 means only
>           apply the tests and actions to the starting-points themselves.
>
>    -mindepth levels
>           Do not apply any tests or actions at levels less than levels
>           (a non-negative integer).  -mindepth 1 means process all files
>           except the starting-points.
> ```

so `-mindepth` mean you get all the files/directories counting current level as one, first level of directories as 2 and so on.

`-maxdepth` mean what is the maximum depth you should search for objects, current one is count as 0

So if we have structure like:

```
.
file1
dir1
 file1
 dir2
  file1
  dir3
   file1
   dir4
    file1
    dir5
     file1
```

in your example we will search for object, named `file1` in `dir1` and below up to `dir5`. So will not find the first `file1` (under the dot)